# How to change audio play speed in PCM playback in javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio, pcm

I am playing an audio PCM stream in javascript and would like to adjust the playback speed? how can I do this?

my relevant piece of code is:

```
const lame    = require('lame');
const request = require('request');
const Speaker = require('speaker');

const decoder = new lame.Decoder();
const speaker = new Speaker({
  channels:   2,
  bitDepth:   16,
  sampleRate: 44100,
  mode:       lame.STEREO,
  device:     'hw:1,0',
});

const req = request.get(url);

req
  .pipe(decoder)
  .pipe(speaker);
```

Regards